# How to add a folder to a android apk use appt and ant

Tags: android, ant, apt

When I use ant tool for build an android project, I do not know how to add custom folders to the apk file, such as a a folder named "running" under the project root, when I use the eclipse can be directly add to apk. I hope you can give me some help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

During the build process, your Android projects are compiled and packaged into an .apk file, the container for your application binary. It contains all of the information necessary to run your application on a device or emulator, such as compiled .dex files (.class files converted to Dalvik byte code), a binary version of the AndroidManifest.xml file, compiled resources (resources.arsc) and uncompiled resource files for your application.

Answer (score -1):

I can't figure out why you need to add the folder to apk, well if you are asking about adding it in the project and later to be accessed in the apk then yes you can place it inside the "assets" folder of your project